# Update nested array field for multiple docs at once

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a huge number of records in the collection on the below structure.

Here I want to update all `floor` fields as an empty string `""`, wherever it's "n/a". It should not affect other blocks which already have value for the floor like the First, Second Floor.

Can someone help on this?

```
{
    "id" : "181",
    "EID" : "83",
    "History" : [ 
        {
            "aNum" : "12324",
            "dev" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : "",
                    "room" : "Office",
                    "floor" : "Second Floor"
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : "",
                    "room" : "Bedroom",
                    "floor" : "n/a"
                },
                {
                    "type" : "",
                    "room" : "Bedroom",
                    "floor" : "First Floor"
                },
                {
                    "type" : "",
                    "room" : "Bedroom",
                    "floor" : "n/a"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `arrayFilters` and [filtered `$[<identifier>]` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#multi-element-array-updates).

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "History.$[].dev.$[dev].floor": ""
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "dev.floor": "n/a"
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Asl42yhPpEY)